# MongoDB query $group is returning null

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am learning MongoDb query and my requirement is to calculate the average time between two dates. I wrote a mongoDB query with project and group stages.

```
{
    project: {
        OrderObject:1,
        date:1
    }
},
{
    group: {
       objectId: '$OrderObject.pharmacy.companyName',
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        },
        duration: {
            $avg: {
                $abs: {
                    $divide: [
                        {
                            $subtract: [
                                {
                                    $arrayElemAt: [
                                        '$date',
                                        0
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    $arrayElemAt: [
                                        '$date',
                                        1
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        60000
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
       
        OrderIDs: {
            $addToSet: '$OrderObject.orderID'
        },
        pharmacyName: {
            $addToSet: '$OrderObject.pharmacy.companyName'
        },
       
    }
}
```

The output I get is

```
  {
    count: 3,
    duration: 54.53004444444445,
    OrderIDs: [ 'ABCDE', 'EWQSE', 'ERTRE' ],
    pharmacyName: [ 'pharmacy business Name' ],
    objectId: null
  },
```

Can someone please tell me why objectId is null in this case but the value is printed in pharmacyName field. I am using this pipeline in parse server as query.aggregate(pipeline, {useMasterKey:true})

The my expectation is pharmacyName === objectId

Comment: Can you provide sample data document to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your nested element here  is with different name:

OrderObject.name.companyName

but this is not an issue for the $group stage since it make the aggregation for all elements( in total 3)  in the collection when the _id is null and do not give you any errors ...
It is also interesing why in your output the "pharmacyName" appear simply as "name" ? ;)

Comment: Hi, I changed the names of the output. Now, they match to the real ones. 
I output is exactly what i was expecting but objectId is null. I except over there is the pharmacyName. I am using parse server as the backend which connects with mongoDb. I guess there is an issue with the parse.